# Ionic zooming image gesture event

Tags: ionic-framework

I have written an ionic app but could not find the right solution for one of my problems. There is a image beeing loaded and i'd like to implement zooming gesture for it , mobile like , swiping with two fingers to zoom in or zoom out. But i can not find it in documentation. Pan event does not do the job since it gets triggered   with one finger. Any ideas or probably workarounds? I have found the npm package ion zoom view but its bugged

Answer (score 0):

1 - Solution 1 user Hammer js to zoom in and out!

2 - Solution 2 use those plugins [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-viewer), [or this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pinch-zoom)